# Вывод данных с БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть кусок кода

```
 $query = "SELECT id, name, lastname, bykva FROM uchenik WHERE bykva='$bykva' AND class=$class";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); $users = array();  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $uc = $row["lastname"] ."&nbsp;". $row["name"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $users[] = "$uc";       
}
```

Если взять `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)` без цикла и вывести, то он выводит тех учеников, которых надо. Пример:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Анель [name] => Анель [2] => Абылкасымова [lastname] => Абылкасымова [3] => Б [bykva] => Б )
```

Но вот в цикле он делает 2 массива, в 1 тех учеников, которые мне нужны, а во 2 уже остальных. И уже присваивает моему массиву $users всех учеников, а не тех которых мне нужно. Пример:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Анель [name] => Анель [2] => Абылкасымова [lastname] => Абылкасымова [3] => Б [bykva] => Б ) Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => Мади [name] => Мади [2] => Рымкулов [lastname] => Рымкулов [3] => А [bykva] => А )
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы в цикле он делал только тех ученикв, которые мне нужны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно оформить SQL запрос, в соответствии с тем, что именно Вам нужно получить на выходе.

Comment: вот я оформил запрос "WHERE bykva='$bykva' AND class=$class" где параметры класс и буква. К примеру я задаю эти параметры 11 Б в 1 случае без цикла он мне выводит правильно учеников с 11 Б, а уже в цикле 1 массив выходит с учениками 11 Б, а дальше уже остальных с других 11, что мне не нужно

Comment: >$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, lastname, bykva FROM uchenik WHERE bykva='$bykva' AND class=$class");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $uc = $row["lastname"] ." ". $row["name"]; $id = $row["id"]; 
 echo $uc.'<br />';
}

пробуйте, ато у вас код как то странно написан, имхо.

Comment: Тоже самое выводит не нужных учеников, где совпадает класс

Comment: это колдовство. кто-то явно сглазил.

Answer (score 1):

Измените

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

на

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

уберите **`$users[] = "$uc";`**

P.S.

Непонятно, зачем вы в запрос передаете переменную **$bykva** и букву получаете запросом.